# All permutations of all components from two lists

Tags: python, permutation

```
operators = ['+', '-', 'x']
numbers = [4,5,6,9]
```

How can I create a list of all possible permutations of possible formulas from two lists?

i.e. 4+5-6x9, 4-5+6x9,..., 9-4+5x6....

For each formula, no duplicates can be used.  Tried various itertools but haven't figured this one out yet.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Can either `operators` or `numbers` contain duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a single function in `itertools` that will do this. You need to calculate the permutations of the operators and numbers separately, then you need to get the cartesian product of both sets of permutations:

```
from itertools import permutations, product
operators = ['+', '-', 'x']
numbers = [4,5,6,9]

all_expressions = set()

for nums, ops in product(permutations(numbers), permutations(operators)):
    expr = "".join(f"{n}{o}" for n, o in zip(nums, ops)) + str(nums[-1])
    all_expressions.add(expr)
```

Creating `all_expressions` as a set takes care of duplicates for you. This gives a set containing 144 elements, as expected:

```
{'4+5-6x9',
 '4+5-9x6',
 '4+5x6-9',
 '4+5x9-6',
 '4+6-5x9',
 ...
 '9x5-6+4',
 '9x6+4-5',
 '9x6+5-4',
 '9x6-4+5',
 '9x6-5+4'}
```

---

`permutations(numbers)` calculates all possible orderings of the `numbers` list. Similarly, `permutations(operators)` calculates all possible orderings of the `operators` list.

The `product` of these two things yields one ordering of `numbers` (in the variable `nums`) and one ordering of `operators` (in the variable `ops`) in each iteration.

For example, in the first iteration, `nums = (4, 5, 6, 9)` and `ops = ('+', '-', 'x')`. Now, we use these to build our expression. `zip(nums, ops)` gives the corresponding elements of either tuple, which we format side-by-side into a string, so the generator expression `f"{n}{o}" for ...` yields the strings `'4+'`, `'5-'`, and `'6x'`.  `"".join(...)` then joins all these strings. Finally, the last element of `nums` is concatenated to the resulting string. The final expression gets added to the set containing all expressions.

Then we rinse and repeat.

Comment: Great solution! I think it would be more helpful for beginners if your solution was broken down into 2 discrete steps: 1) get all permutations for nums + operators (ex: `4+6`)... then 2) all permutations for those combos `(X+Y){op}(Z-Y)`

Comment: @YaakovBressler that's not quite what this solution does, I'll add some more detail to the explanation shortly

Comment: @YaakovBressler `{n}` _is_ `4|5|6`. `f"{n}{o}"` is `4+|5-|6x`, all of which then get joined. `nums` and `ops` contain the different arrangements of the numbers / operators that come from the product of the permutations of `numbers` and `operators`

Comment: TY for your detailed responses.

Answer (score 4):

```py
from itertools import permutations

operators = ['+', '-', 'x']
numbers = [4,5,6,9]

formulas = [
    ''.join(a)
    for a in [[None] * 7]
    for a[::2] in permutations(map(str, numbers))
    for a[1::2] in permutations(operators)
]

print(formulas)
```

Result ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZA9DsIwDIX3nMJbWkiRQPxW4gpcIMoQpFYEkThKXQnOwtIF7sRVmAi0hQ54sGR_evbTu979hQ7omuZWU5mtH88yoAVDRSDEUwXGegwEvgi2Jk0GXcUYxlEThgq2IPmYC-DZu525Yq62-6Ilc7EQS7FRjJUY5Sf92TKIxfnkiMYlOv2MkYMG40DKHbpCwQhW6kdkns_UGw9tJFb7pKIgoHuZDm7J6V_J13jKoisfjKOk95a2CXRB9IG8AA)):

```
['4+5-6x9', '4+5x6-9', '4-5+6x9', '4-5x6+9', '4x5+6-9', '4x5-6+9',
 '4+5-9x6', ...,
 ...
 '9+6-5x4', '9+6x5-4', '9-6+5x4', '9-6x5+4', '9x6+5-4', '9x6-5+4']
```

Comment: Nice solution! I've never seen a list created inside a list comprehension modified by a deeper loop, I learned a new trick today :)

Comment: @pho Yeah, I like doing/sharing such trickery. Also the way *how* I modify the list, I think only few people know that we can use slices as `for`-targets (although it's rare that that's useful, that's perhaps the bigger reason I've almost never seen someone else do that).

Comment: The code is kind of unreadable (no offence), but it shows a Python master at work.

Comment: @Matthias Hmm, I'm of course biased since I wrote it, but I'm confident I'd have no trouble reading it if someone else had written it. It's really straightforward. Would a better name than `a` help? I considered `buffer` and `template` but was too lazy to make up my mind and was happy enough with the way it is.

Comment: To understand these nested loops with slices as `for` targets takes some time, and since you don't see this kind of code very often, it really really really takes some time - at least for me.